# Почему булевая переменная не меняет свой статус?

Tags: c#, unity3d

пытаюсь сделать спейс-шутер на Unity и прописываю код и не могу понять в чем моя ошибка и почему булевая переменная не меняет свой статус при соприкосновении объектов с триггером и из-за этого дальше код не может срабатывать корректно. Что делать?

```
 public bool detect = true;
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
     if(collision.CompareTag("Alien") && detect)
     {
         detect = false;
         collision.GetComponentInParent<Wave>().WaveTouchBumper();
         StartCoroutine(wait());
     }
 }

 IEnumerator wait()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
     detect = true;
 }
```

Comment: В таких случаях, значения по типу `collision.CompareTag("Alien")` выносят в отдельную переменную (например, `var tag = collision.CompareTag("Alien"); if (tag && detect){ ... }`), ставят точку остановки и проверяют чему эти все значения равны, подходят ли они под ожидаемое. Это называется "отладка", попробуйте.

Comment: А вообще CompareTag не используют из за строковых литералов и отсутствия зависимостей. Можно же по компоненту wave проверить, хотя как то странно, что ты ищешь его у родителя..

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected bool detect = true;
 public bool Detect => detect;
 protected void SetDetect(bool _detect, string source)
 {
   detect = _detect;
   string s = $"{this.имя_или_идентификатор} Detect by {source ?? string.Empty}";
   Console.WriteLine(s); //или какая там консоль в унити
 }
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
     if(collision.CompareTag("Alien") && detect)
     {
         SetDetect(false, "OnTriggerEnter2D");
         collision.GetComponentInParent<Wave>().WaveTouchBumper();
         StartCoroutine(wait());
     }
 }

 IEnumerator wait()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
     SetDetect(true, "IEnumerator wait()");
 }
```

Comment: Хорошо бы код как-то пояснять всё-таки - в чём суть его различий с кодом в вопросе. В чём основная идея.

Comment: @CrazyElf основная идея в Console.WriteLine, а точнее в его аналоге для унити